# How to use volley inside alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-alertdialog

Here let me explain my issue need to add volley inside alertdialog which i have done successfully its like pinging the entered Url its working fine but what I need to do is in onErrorResponse method alert dialog gets hide suppose when user enter wrong url it will go to onErrorResponse method  in this my alertdialog gets hide need to stay awake the dialog even when error gets occurred so far what I have tried is:

This is my code:

```
   final     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle("Add Self Hosted URL "); //Set Alert dialog title here
        alert.setMessage("Enter The Url Here"); //Message here
        final       EditText input = new EditText(context);
        alert.setView(input);
    ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) PingingActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected()) {

           final  ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.hide();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Pinging Please Wait");
                    final String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, srt,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    Log.e("resp", response);
                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PingingActivity.id, 0); // 0 - for private mode
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                    editor.putString("Url", srt);
                                    editor.putBoolean("URLflag", true);
                                    editor.apply();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //  alert.show();

                            //       input.setText(srt);
                            //final String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                            String str = error.toString();
                            if (str != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check the Entered URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                  progressDialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }
                    });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.

                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                    Toast.makeText(context, srt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp).show(); //End of alert.setNegativeButton

       /* Alert Dialog Code End*/

        }


        else {
            showAlertDialog("No Network", "Please Check Your Network Connectivity", true);
        }
```

even in onerrorresponse need to display my alertdialog how can i achieve this. It may be a dumb question but as a beginner am struggling with this can anyone help me

Comment: This is because your request is happening over Ok button click of alert.

Comment: Then what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool method returning the status , call it

> alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

return true from response and false from onError()

if the response return success start your desired Activity , otherwise let the alert dialog show.